# Does Azure NSG applied at the subnet level affects communication between VMs on that subnet?

Tags: azure, network-security-groups

If you have a NSG at the Subnet level, will it be applied between VMs that resides in the same subnet?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does apply to VMs within the same subnet. As per [NSG documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview#intra-subnet-traffic):

*It's important to note that security rules in an NSG associated to a subnet can affect connectivity between VM's within it.*